# Action Bar Compat Display icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am developing an android app and need to have an Action Bar for the same.
I referred a lot of sites and have got an output but it is like a list rather than an action Bar which i need

```
main.xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:title="@string/home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/user"
    android:title="@string/profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/user"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/notification"
    android:title="@string/notification"
    android:icon="@drawable/world"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/sell"
    android:title="@string/sell"
    android:icon="@drawable/book"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

activity.java

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        //actionBar.show();


 }@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Phone",        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.search:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Computer",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.user:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Gamepad",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.notification:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.sell:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            }
        return true;
    }

}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.parseprc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"  >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.parseprc.Main_activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.parseprc.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.parseprc.register"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.parseprc.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 

         android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.parseprc.Forgotpassword"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

i need the output like how instagram and twitter have the actionbar

But all i get is a list of options

Comment: saying "like Twitter" doesn't help, because not everyone uses Twitter. You should attempt to provide some way for us to know your current and expected results.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b93oxjz2antld82/z9ligZ3RIR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try change

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

to

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```